# excel error replace #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I receive page numbers in an email and have been successful at using the split function to get them into excel but my problem is sometimes they come in with an S in front of them
Here is how they will come in:
S55-65
55-65

now i can split them further and I have 2 columns

If they come in as S55-65

```
      A         B
1    S55       55
2   -65       -65
3  #VALUE!     10
```

For column A 
 I add the 2 together to get the total number of pages but since it has an S the value is #VALUE!

For column B the value is 10

If they come in as 55-65

```
      A           B
1   S55        #VALUE!
2   -65       -65
3    10        #VALUE!
```

B1 is an error because it uses a split to get rid of the S

In a separate cell I would like a code that would allow for the correct answer to show if either A3 or B3 show #VALUE!.

I have tried using
=IF(ERROR.TYPE(A3) = 3,B3,A3) but I cannot get that to work

Comment: Why not `=IfError([formula],[what to do if error])`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you it worked perfectly. I am self taught with excel so your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more recent Excel version, you can use `IfError()`: 
`=IfError([Formula],[what to do if the formula returns an error])`.

If you have an older Excel without that function, you can use a combination `If()` statement:
`=If(IsError([formula]),[what to do if error],[formula])`

Or

`=If(IsErr([formula]),[what to do if error],[formula])`

The difference in `IsError` and `IsErr` is (from [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665))

> ISERR - Value refers to any error value except #N/A. 
>   ISERROR - Value refers to any error value (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!).

You can also just check for `#N/A` error with `IsNA()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here my example

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(F7,"Acve","Red","Se","InvO","PO","Susactive","Suspense Other","Del","I223","Penng","PEO Cond","Invesyed"), " ")
```

Excel

[image]